# export the email body to html file in java

Tags: java, html, gmail, aspose

I want to export the email body part (from gmail) in HTML file using java.I want to read the email from gmail and export that using java.This email body may/may not contain the table data. i have already tried the few API for the same.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I think you forgot the question part of your question.  You need to show what you have done and explain any issues with your solution.   You may want to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DaImTo : I have tried the java email api, aspose api and some third party tools also. I got the data in html format but minor data loss and not proper format. I feel that java api is more useful  than aspose.email for my requirement. I have data in table and key-value pair format. i want to export the data in html format using java code from gmail without using outlook or any other tool.

Comment: Sounds like a good project.  However there still doesn't seem to be any question for us to help with

Comment: if anybody share any link / code / API name to read the gmail email body part and save that as HTML file, its really very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.Email for Java API lets you connect to a number of servers using it's POP3 and IMAP clients. Gmail is also one of them that you can connect to and retrieve emails from. The emails are retrieved as EML using MailMessage class of the API that can be saved to HTML then as shown in the code sample below.

```
ImapClient client = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", port, "Username", "Password");

client.setSecuirtyOptions(SecurityOptions.Auto);

client.selectFolder(ImapFolderInfo.IN_BOX);

MailMessage eml = client.fetchMessage(0);   //fetch the 1st message

HtmlSaveOptions options = SaveOptions.getDefaultHtml();

options.setEmbedResources(false);

options.setHtmlFormatOptions(HtmlFormatOptions.WriteHeader |HtmlFormatOptions.WriteCompleteEmailAddress);

eml.save("SavingMessageAsHTML_out2.html", options);
```

If this doesn't meet your requirements, you can share your scenario with us with the help of a sample message file/view using [Aspose.Email forum](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.email-product-family/188/showforum.aspx) where we'll be able to assist you further as per your requirements.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.